# Should we have easily searchable questions here?

Tags: discussion

Area 51 metrics suggest that we should have over 90% traffic from search engines. Now, suppose that you are a user, who is not associated with Aviation.SE in anyway. You search for something like "How is an aircraft tracked in sky?"

Since Aviation.SE has one of the best SEO ratings, our results are always on top. So, having such basic posts should certainly bring in some more traffic. I would suggest that such posts should be tagged [esq](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esq) a temporary tag, which shall be deleted later on. The tag wiki of this tag should be :
`"Answers to this question must be original, and not quote from any other source".`

Answer (score 9):

"temporary" and "meta" tags like [esq](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esq) go against the grain of the tagging system: It's supposed to be a taxonomy of questions ("All these questions are about [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations)", "All these questions are about [weather](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather)", etc.).

By definition any question asked here is "Easily Searchable":

- Google likes us.
  (God only knows why)
- The site has a search box.
  (Please don't use it, it's terrible. Use Google instead. Google likes us.)
- You can click into any of our [tags](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags) and browse the questions to find one that interests you.
  (Remember? This is how we used to search for things at the library Back In The Day, when the "card catalog" was actual cards on paper in drawers.... shut up and get off my lawn ya darn kids!)

---

I also have a separate issue with the proposed tag wiki (`Answers to this question must be original, and not quote from any other source`) -- There are a lot of questions that have been answered comprehensively and well [in FAA publications](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/) -- many (maybe even most) of my answers steal liberally from these.

Quoting and citing authoritative references allows users to continue their own research, which is something we should be encouraging as much as possible

Comment: Many of us are not pilots and wouldn't have a clue where to search in the FAA publications, so quoting from them and linking to them is very helpful. Also, since flight is a very highly regulated activity in all countries around the world, regulatory answers are often not only the correct one, but the _only_ valid answer to flight related questions.

Comment: @FreeMan you'd be surprised how many pilots don't know about the FAA publications, or how many times you stumble on one you've never heard of before even when you know they're out there. The list is rather extensive: that page is just their handbooks, there are also "Advisory Circulars", some of which [(like AC 43.13)](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/99861) are book-length in themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, we're at about 80% search engine traffic, 15% referring traffic, and 5% direct. Page views have been growing almost linearly since launch, and the more page views grow, generally the larger percentage of that traffic will be from search engines. There's no reason to think our breakdown of traffic is currently anything but good. Also, that 90% figure is rather arbitrary, like everything else on Area 51. It's not a requirement, nor does it necessarily represent the ideal for every site.

As for basic "searchable" questions, I would prefer to see them pop up naturally, rather than asking questions purely for SEO value. Private beta was certainly a "seeding" period, but we're long since past that. If you have a genuine interest in a question, and feel like others would benefit from it, then feel free to ask it. I'm just saying, don't feel like it's necessary for the success of the site.

Comment: As for the site search box, you are correct, it it hopelessly bad. I do hate, though, having to go to Google to search for something i know would be answered accurately on SE and sometimes have it buried under a bunch of terrible, opinion-based Yahoo answers. (Google likes them too) Especially since I use the Android app a lot. I have seen sites that have a "Google custom search" box which apparently uses Google's resources for internal searches. I assume Google probably charges sites for that but i don't know. It might be worthwhile for someone at  SE to look into it.